# $P, Q$ are symmetric square. If $P \geq Q > 0$ then show $P^{-1} \leq Q^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [inequalty concering inverses of positive definite matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214126/inequalty-concering-inverses-of-positive-definite-matrix)
>   [Is $B^{-1}-A^{-1}$ a positive definite matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236431/is-b-1-a-1-a-positive-definite-matrix)

$P, Q$ are symmetric square. If $P \geq Q > 0$ then show $P^{-1} \leq Q^{-1}$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should probably clarify that $\ge$ means that the difference is positive (or nonnegative) definite.  I was reading it as a componentwise inequality...

Answer (score 3):

We can prove this using the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric matrices and $A \geq B$, then $M^T A M \geq M^T B M$ for any $M$.  We'll also use the fact that if $I \geq A > 0$, then $I \leq A^{-1}$.

Let $P = L L^T$ be a Cholesky factorization of $P$.  Then
\begin{align*}
& P \geq Q > 0 \\
\implies& L L^T \geq Q > 0 \\
\implies& I \geq L^{-1} Q L^{-T} > 0\\
\implies& I \leq L^T Q^{-1} L  \\
\implies& L^{-T} L^{-1} \leq Q^{-1}  \\
\implies& P^{-1} \leq Q^{-1} .
\end{align*}