# Proof that for two invertible symmetric matrices, $ A \preccurlyeq B \iff A^{-1} \preccurlyeq B^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

For invertible symmetric matrices $A$, $B$, I want to show that $$ A \preccurlyeq B \iff  A^{-1} \preccurlyeq B^{-1}$$

More concretely, I tried to argue the following. Denote by $\lambda_{S_{min}}$ and $\lambda_{S_{max}}$ the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $S$.
Then 
\begin{align}
A \preccurlyeq B & \iff  \forall x, x^\top A x \leq x^\top B x \\ 
& \iff \lambda_{A_{min}} \leq \lambda_{B_{min}} \\
& \iff \frac{1}{\lambda_{A_{max}}} \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_{B_{max}}}\\
& \iff \lambda_{A^{-1}_{max}} \leq \lambda_{B^{-1}_{max}} \\
& \iff \forall x, x^\top A^{-1} x \leq x^\top B^{-1} x \\
& \iff  A^{-1} \preccurlyeq B^{-1}
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Update: The result should be $A \preccurlyeq B \iff  A^{-1} \succcurlyeq B^{-1}$ for **positive definite** matrices. The fixed proof:
\begin{align}
A \preccurlyeq B & \iff  \forall x, x^\top A x \leq x^\top B x \\ 
& \iff \lambda_{A_{max}} \leq \lambda_{B_{min}} \\
& \iff \frac{1}{\lambda_{A_{max}}} \geq \frac{1}{\lambda_{B_{min}}}\\
& \iff \lambda_{A^{-1}_{min}} \geq \lambda_{B^{-1}_{max}} \\
& \iff \forall x, x^\top A^{-1} x \geq x^\top B^{-1} x \\
& \iff  A^{-1} \succcurlyeq B^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: shouldn't it be $A^{-1}\geq B^{-1}$? Look at the case $A,B\in\Bbb R^{1\times 1}$

Comment: yes, that's why I'm confused. Please point out where the proof may have gone wrong.

Comment: If $A\in\Bbb R^{1\times 1}$, then $\lambda_{A_{min}}=\lambda_{A_{max}}=A$. Same for $B$. Reread your equation for this special case. You will see the mistake (from second to third line).

Comment: Yes, it looks much better.

Comment: Related: [Inequality concerning inverses of positive definite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214126), [Is $B^{-1}-A^{-1}$ a positive definite matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236431)