# A - B positive semidefinite and eigenvalues of A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm looking at the proof in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118172/proof-that-for-two-invertible-symmetric-matrices-a-preccurlyeq-b-iff-a-1?noredirect=1&lq=1), and I can't convince myself that this is correct (assuming $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and positive definite):
$$\forall x\; x^T Ax \ge x^T Bx \iff \lambda_{min}(A) \ge \lambda_{max}(B).$$

Intuitively, it *kinda* makes sense because every $x$ can be expressed as a linearly combination of the eigenvectors of $A$ or $B$. However, although I can convince myself that the RHS implies the LHS, I can't convince myself of the other direction. It seems possible that the RHS is sufficient but not necessary for the LHS.

So does the statement actually hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHS $\implies$ LHS but not the other way around. A straightforward counterexample is given by
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
B = \begin{pmatrix} 3/4 & 0 \\
0 & 1/4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The difference $A-B$ is positive definite but $\lambda_{\min}(A) = 1/2 \not\geq 3/4 = \lambda_{\max}(B)$.